# "spark.sql.execution.id is already set" exception on SparkSQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm facing this exception with spark-sql over hive tables. This happens specifically when my query has both WITH and INSERT clauses, i.e., it works if I remove the WITH clause or if I replace INSERT:

```
sql("WITH... SELECT...").write.parquet("/test/")
```

I'm using spark 1.6.0 on CDH 5.7 and spark 1.6.1 on HD Insight.

Any ideas?

The same exception has been related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712575/spark-1-6-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-spark-sql-execution-id-is-already) but for other reasons.
A ticket exists related to this exception [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10548).

Answer (score 1):

Spark 1.6.0 does not support common table expression(CTE) when you try to invoke sqlcontext(which is actually hive context), This is why you are getting this error.Please rewrite your CTE to a regular query.

Comment: I don't understand. So why does sqlContext.sql("WITH... SELECT...").write.parquet("/test/") work?