# 'spark.sql.execution.id is already set' Exception using SparkSQL and Futures

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, future

Using Spark *2.0.2.6* and Scala *2.11.8*: I've been coming across an exception `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: spark.sql.execution.id is already set` when trying to do a .collect() / .show() on a DataFrame when executing through a `Future`.

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}

def printTable(query: String): Unit = {
  try { 
    spark.sql(query).show 
  }
  catch { case e: Exception => println(e) }
}

Future {
  printTable("SELECT key1, key2 FROM schema.table1 LIMIT 1")
}

Future {
  printTable("SELECT key1, key2 FROM schema.table2 LIMIT 1")
}

Future {
  printTable("SELECT key1, key2 FROM schema.table3 LIMIT 1")
}
```

Also: the error is in no way consistent and the code sometimes prints back the right answer.

What's going on here and how do I fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34712575/spark-1-6-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-spark-sql-execution-id-is-already/34759307

Comment: @SoheilPourbafrani yes, I did google the error before posting this question. Updating Spark may fix this, but will have to undergo more tests.